# Is there a way to build the dockeized image directly from the server?

Tags: java, linux, windows, docker

I have docker installed on my server which is the linux machine , and I am coding from the other system(windows) , is there anyway to create the dockerized image directly from the server ?
Here is the file I am using .

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=cobra-master-data-management-deploy/target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} sample.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/sample.jar"]
```

Is there anyway to replace `ARG JAR_FILE` with the server's path or any other way so that it directly creates the image from the server without needing to copy and paste the files to server and then creating the image ??

Comment: What advantage would you expect to gain by building the image on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace value of your `ARG` by passing it to `docker build` command: `docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=path/to/files/*.jar Dockerfile`

Maybe it would be reasonable to think of Docker images repository? You could set it up on your server or somewhere else where the server can read it and then you could build image locally and upload the image to this repo and just pull it on your server from the repo.